# Installing RBS for Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, remote-blob-storage

I have posted other questions about this but no answers were given so I deleted them and thought I would try one last time before calling it a day...

I am trying to install RBS for SharePoint Foundation 2010 but I am not getting any confirmation in the log file that is generated from the command:

```
msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log.txt /i RBS.msi TRUSTSERVERCERTIFICATE=true FILEGROUP=PRIMARY DBNAME="WSS_Content" DBINSTANCE="<server name>" FILESTREAMFILEGROUP=RBSFilestreamProvider FILESTREAMSTORENAME=FilestreamProvider_1
```

I don't see any new tables created in SQL Server.

I am at my wits end because I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on here or Google.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, run the `RBS_x64.msi` directly (double click on it). It'll walk through a wizard and create everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Start Command Prompt using the Run as administrator option.

```
msiexec /qn /lvx* rbs_install_log.txt /i RBS.msi TRUSTSERVERCERTIFICATE=true
FILEGROUP=PRIMARY DBNAME="SP_Content" DBINSTANCE="SP2010-WFE1"
FILESTREAMFILEGROUP=RBSFilestreamProvider FILESTREAMSTORENAME=FilestreamProvider_1
```

to Confirm the installation of RBS,

- open rbs_install_Log.txt, and then confirm that you see the following
  line within the last 20 lines of the end of the file: Product: SQL
  Server 2008 R2 Remote Blob Store -- Installation completed
  successfully.
- In SQL Server Management Studio, refresh the view of the Object Explorer tree, and then verify that several tables exist in the target content database that have names that begin with the letters mssqlrbs.

then enable RBS for your content database via SP2010 Management Shell, enable RBS for the WSS_Content_Intranet_IT database by typing the following commands:

```
$cdb = Get-SPContentDatabase "SP_Content_DB"
$rbss = $cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbss.Installed()
$rbss.Enable()
$rbss.SetActiveProviderName($rbss.GetProviderNames()[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  It's helped a bit but still problems.  My logfile has grown immensely in size, but that states that the installation is complete nor are there any tables starting with mssqlrbs.  I have haven't tried the enabling RBS step yet.

Answer (score 1):

I spend 4 days settings this up at an environment. Very important to notice when you are troubleshooting the RBS.

Do not - EVER - use `$rbss.Disable()` on your database in SP Shell because this causes your database to be corrupt for RBS-usage.

You can save yourself by restoring the database back-up which (I hope) you created before installing RBS.

When you want to disable RBS, just set the Active Provider to none:

```
$rbss.SetActiveProvider("")
```

I hope I can save some lives with this, had to search deep into all technets/blog posts to see where this was coming from.