# Remote Blob Storage problem

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am using http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx#enable steps for installing RBS on SP Foundation 2010

I am installing RBS.msi on my content database but cannot see the tables by RBS in it after installation, I have checked and I am running the command prompt with admin priveleges but still no tables, why ?

Let me know Thanks.

Comment: What tables are you looking for?

Comment: the tables which are created by the RBS client library setup like eg: mssqlrbs_nameoftable

Comment: Ok, please give use more details about what steps you've done and any (error/information)messages.

Comment: I enable the filestream on sql server instance on which sp 2010 is running its content db. Then I executed the four queries to enable Blob storage in sql server. Then I download the RBS Client library setup and run it through command prompt with admin rights. I checked its log files and I can see it says that setup completed successfully but still I cannot see the RBS tables in my sp sites content db

Comment: Have you executed the required PowerShell on the CDB?

Comment: Yes I had executed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a frequent issue. The command prompt didn't work for me either. Just double click on the MSI and walk through the wizard. It'll work correctly then.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

One user had a similar issue while installing & configuring RBS. I've described the process here [Installing RBS for Foundation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34241/installing-rbs/34739#34739) which also includes some troubleshooting steps.

Have a look and let us know if that helps you troubleshoot!

Comment: I have tried it but no success yet, No tables found still